# Is there a proper order in which to add controls to nested panels?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have odd drawing of `Controls` within `FlowLayoutPanels` happening when I change the order of when the `Controls` are added to the `FlowLayoutPanels` and when those panels are added to a main panel.

Specifically, I have groups of `Controls` I wish to show together. I add the `Controls` in a group to a `FlowLayoutPanel` and add all of these panels to a main `FlowLayoutPanel`. Now, if if I add the child `FlowLayoutPanels` to the main (`mainPanel.Controls.Add(childPanel)`) before adding the `Controls` to the child, the `Controls` are drawn properly. If I add all of the `Controls` to the child `FlowLayoutPanel` then add the panel to the main panel, all of the `Controls` are drawn in-properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not glitch if you first call `SuspendLayout`:

```
this.SuspendLayout();

// ... add controls

this.ResumeLayout();
```

Comment: Should I do this for all the nested controls too? (Doing it just for the form itself changes nothing)

Comment: Don't have an environment ready now, but I think it was on the `Control` you are adding the new controls to, so in your case the `FlowLayoutPanel`.

Comment: This somewhat worked. I think the drawing issues now have to do with how the panels attributes are setup. This set me on the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: @user1596244: Glad I could help you. Note that this also should increase your performance a lot. Good luck with that!